# How to recursively change names of files to match?

Tags: bash, regular-expression, rename, wildcards

I'm trying to change the names of multiple files recursively within a directory, looking something like this:

```
parentdirectory/dir1/foo_1.txt
               /dir2/bar_1.txt
               /dir3/foo_2.txt
```

Because a tool that I'm using won't recognize wildcards, I would like to remove the text from each file ending in '1.txt', such that each instance matches exactly.

I can generate a list of those files to STDOUT and pipe it somewhere with:

```
find . -name '*1.txt' -print0 |
```

...But I'm not sure how to write the regular expression that (I assume) exists to rename the files. Additionally, *rename* is not installed with my setup, and I don't have the permissions to add it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your find statement in a for loop and use shell substring replacement. Something like this.

```
for file_name in $(find . -name '*1.txt' -print0); do
    #echo mv -v "$file_name" "${file_name/substring_to_be_replaced/the_replacement_substring}"
    mv -v "$file_name" "${file_name/substring_to_be_replaced/the_replacement_substring}"
done
```

Just put your values in `substring_to_be_replaced` and `the_replacement_substring`. For more information how to replace a substring look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210880/replace-one-substring-for-another-string-in-shell-script.

And use the commented out echo statement first to make sure your substring substitution and find work correctly. When you are sure everything is fine, comment out echo and  use the actual `mv` statement. Once you start `mv` with wrong parameters it is very difficult or even impossible to undo.

Comment: See [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice).   Use `find ... -exec ...` instead of `for file in $(find ...)`.  Better yet, use the perl rename utility for bulk renaming operations.